# How can I add multiple values associated with a key in python

Tags: python-2.7, list

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=['a','b','c','d']
```

Now i need to convert them into a dictionary by

```
final_list = dict(zip(list1,list2))
```

I need to add values:

```
1:a,m,o
2:b,y,z
..
```

Comment: Where does the `m`, `o`, `y`, `z` come from. Are these meant to be lists in the dictionary, or strings?

Comment: strings.........

Comment: It is still unclear where the other characters come from.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to add multiple values to a single key in a dictionary. Either assign the value of the key an array or another dictionary. Here is how you could assign it an array

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=['a','b','c','d']

final_list = dict(zip(list1,list2))

final_list[1] = ['x', 'y', 'z']

print final_list[1]

final_list[1].append('aa')

print final_list[1]
```

This can also be simply created and modified from scratch, without the unnecessary steps in the beginning

```
final_list = {1: ['x', 'y', 'z'], 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}

print final_list[1]

final_list[1].append('aa')

print final_list
```

Comment: how can you add values into this??

Comment: edited to demonstrate appending to this list. also added code showing how to do this starting fresh

Comment: final_list[1] = ['x', 'y', 'z'] all time i have to initialise it to an array then only in can append it.. ?

Comment: You have to initialize your dictionary and set the value of one of the keys, to a list. In the example I provided (the edited one) the first line initializes the dictionary, sets the key '1' in the dictionary to have a value of a list (['x', 'y', 'z']). Now that the value is a list, we can use standard list functions

Answer (score 0):

You can concatentate to the strings contained in d. There are a few ways, the easiest is to use the `+=` operator:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=['a','b','c','d']
d = dict(zip(list1,list2))

d[1] += ',m,o'
d[2] += ',y,z'
...
```

Following this dictionary `d` will be:

```
{1: 'a,m,o', 2: 'b,y,z', ...}
```

Comment: we have  to add not contactinate

Comment: @Pam: what is the difference?